# How to add blinking effect for the dynamically generated div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add spontaneous blinking effect by default (without clicking on the divs) to the dynamically generated divs given in the below link.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ramapriya/xeYnv/1/

```js
function get_random_color() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return color;
}

var columns = 40,
  container = $("#container"),
  width = (100 / columns);

$("head").append("<style>.col { width: " + width + "%;} .row {  height: " + width + "%  }</style>");

for (var ii = 0; ii < columns; ii++) {
  var $row = $("<div />", {
    class: "row"
  });
  container.append($row);

  for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    var $col = $("<div />", {
      class: "col",
      style: "background: " + get_random_color() + ";",
      id: ii + "-" + i
    });
    $row.append($col);
  }
}

$("div.col").click(function() {
  alert(this.id + " " + $(this).html());
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You need each div to blink individually ? :|

Comment: Yes i need to make each div to blink individually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it by randomly selecting your `.col` div's by `eq()` and adding to them blink effect by, for example `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions.

Add this function:

```
function blink(){
    $('.col').eq(Math.round(Math.random() * (40 * 40)))
    .fadeOut('fast')
    .fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Then call `blink` function in `setInterval(blink,100);` to start the effect.

[Here is an example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nndd9/97/)

And here is example snippet:

```js
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

function blink(){
    $('.col').eq(Math.round(Math.random() * (40 * 40)))
    .fadeOut('fast')
    .fadeIn('fast');
}

var columns = 40,
    container = $("#container"),
    width = (100 / columns);

$("head").append("<style>.col { width: " + width + "%;} .row {  height: " + width + "%  }</style>");

for (var ii = 0; ii < columns; ii++) {
    var $row = $("<div />", {
        class: "row"
    });
    container.append($row);

    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        var $col = $("<div />", {
            class: "col",
            style: "background: " + get_random_color() + ";",
            id : ii + "-" + i
        });
        $row.append($col);
    }
}

$("div.col").click(function () {
    alert(this.id + " " + $(this).html());
});

setInterval(blink,100);
```

```css
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
}
.col { 
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px solid purple;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it affects any other functioning but it works

```
<div id='blink_me'>Text You want to blink goes here...!</div>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     hideMe();
     });


    function showMe(){
       $('#blink_me').fadeIn(700);
       hideMe();
    }


    function hideMe(){
      $('#blink_me').fadeOut(700);
      showMe();
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text You want to blink goes here...!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 blinkMe();
 });


function blinkMe(){
   $('#blink_me').fadeOut(700).fadeIn(700);
   setTimeout(blinkMe,100);// or blinkMe();
}
```